# Sending requests for using an application via Facebook iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, facebook

Is there any way I can send a message like "Username invites you to use Application" (it should appear on the notifications tab) using the current Facebook iOS SDK?

I believe such can be done using FBML (see http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/), but I don't think the SDK can render FBML yet.

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no support for this through the iOS SDK or any API call.